# PHP: get substring of string from start to the 3rd occurrence of '%'

Tags: php, regex, string, split, percentage

I got a different strings with lists of percentages:

```
'51% 20% 19% 6% 3% 2% 2% ...'
```

How can I cut the string to:

```
'51% 20% 19%'
```

Maybe some regex?

Comment: split to array using space as delimiter, join it's first 3 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match up until the `3`rd occurrence of the percent sign.

```
$str = '51% 20% 19% 6% 3% 2% 2%';
preg_match('/^(?:[^%]*%){3}/', $str, $match);
echo $match[0];                 //=> "51% 20% 19%"
```

A verbose way would be..

```
$str = '51% 20% 19% 6% 3% 2% 2%';
$val = explode(' ', $str);
echo "$val[0] $val[1] $val[2]"; //=> "51% 20% 19%"
```